# This question requires bearing and trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

You are the pilot of a light aircraft, returning to the airfield after a parachuting trip. Your altitude is $3.05$ km and you are heading towards the landing strip which is currently $14$ km away. What angle of depression should you use so that you touch down on the landing strip at the closest point?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: I tried solving this, but i don't think it is correct.

Comment: the angle of depression = tangent inverse of (3.05/ 14) which gives you the answer of approximately 12.40

Comment: OK, I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight ambiguity in the question. It is not made clear if the distance refers to the *line of sight distance* or *(level) ground distance*.

If it's the former, then the distance would comprise the hypotenuse of the right triangle, so the answer is $\arcsin \frac{3.05}{14} \approx 12.58^{\circ}$

If it's the latter (as you assumed), then the distance would comprise the adjacent side of the right triangle, so the answer is $\arctan \frac{3.05}{14} \approx 12.29^{\circ}$

(I'm not sure how you got your value, maybe you made a calculation error. You didn't state units of angle either).

When the distance is large, it doesn't matter very much (as the tangent and sine of small angles are very close). However, in this case, there is quite a difference.

I would probably go with the first assumption (line of sight distance) and the first answer. If you are using a computerised marking system, you might try both answers (make sure you answer to the expected degree of precision, i.e. number of decimal places).

Comment: Than you so much, a lifesaver!

Comment: Distance in aviation is ground distance.  However, the 1/4 degree difference  is imperceptible.

Comment: I don't think thats the case but thank you anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

ugh the metric system has no place in aviation.

And the cockpit is not the place to be doing math.

Here is how a pilot would answer the question:

altitude is measured in ft.  $3.05 km = 10,000 ft$

Distance in nautical miles.

$14 km$ is $7.5 miles$ (nautical)

$10,000 ft$ over $7 miles$ is an unsafe rate of descent, the pilot needs to circle to lose altitude.

I like to plan for 4 miles per thousand feet of altitude I need to lose.